# Boolean modifier leaves a hole in the object

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

I am working on patterning a wheel with a cylinder shape. See the image below:

[image]

I am using a very simple Booleam Modifier:

[image]

It worked in like 99% of the cases, but for some reason, at a specific angle it leaves a hole in the object:

[image]

I don't know why at this position, nothing chaged, the object is the same as in the last x positions, the modifier is the same. Moving the objects to another location does not help. Making the cylinder a bit larger or smaller does not help either. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: did you try changing to solver-fast?

Comment: yes, but with the fast option selected, it does not do anything, as if I did not apply the modifier at all.

Comment: ok, pls provide blend file, thx